# Extensible typing system for a strongly-typed DSL

Tags: c, interpreter, compiler, dsl

I recently finished cleaning up my code in a compiler/interpreter for a strongly-typed domain-specific language, which makes use of three sorts of types:

**Compile-time enumerated types**: Have one of a set of values, defined at compile time (ex. type 'direction' has values 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right')

**Run-time enumerated types**: Have one of a set of values, loaded from external data somehow at compile time (ex. 'music' has values that are the names of .wav files in a particular folder at runtime)

**Numeric types**: Have a value that is a number

Some types are purely enumerative, associating a collection of string labels with a collection of indices, while others have additional information associated with them.

My goal with this code was to have a system that is extensible, requiring as little effort as possible to add new types as they become necessary, flexible, able to handle a wide variety of types, and modular so that individual types could be changed or removed without affecting any other code and as much as possible could be done in a type-agnostic way. It proved a frustrating, but enlightening, experience. All raw data is stored in a binary format, either as an index for enumerated types or as a number for numeric types, and the possible values for enumerated types are recorded as strings both to be used to generate file paths and for debugging purposes.

The sample code I'm including here is not for the entire compiler/interpreter, but specifically for the code that defines and maintains the type system, which functions largely independently, and is meant to give an overview of what's possible using the system.

While I'm generally happy with it, I would especially like advice on how to avoid the `#define` statements that are singled out in my comments, as they feel arbitrary to me (I know that C++ has a feature that would allow me to define a reference to an array element, but am not interested in trying to port the code at this time).

I hope I explained how this works well enough in the comments, I've lived in it for so long at this point that it's hard to tell what's obvious and what isn't. If it's confusing, let me know and I can try to clarify.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//First, some useful macros and a useful function, both defined elsewhere in my real code but relevant here.
#define DEBUG(message,...) printf(message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERROR(code, message,...) printf(message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__); return code

//Compares two strings, returns 1 if they're the same and 0 if not or if either is null.
int str_compare(const char* A, const char* B){
    if(!(B&&A)){ return 0; }
    int i = 0;
    while(A[i] && B[i] && (A[i]==B[i])){ i++; }
    return (A[i]==B[i]) ? 1:0;
}

//Types:
//    (I'd love to not define all my enum/char* array pairs manually in this way,
//     but macros just aren't up to the task of automating this it seems.)
typedef enum{ type_fnc, type_dir, type_scr, type_mus, type_num, type_count } VAR_TYPE;
const char* type_names[] = {
  //compile-time enumerated types
    "function",
    "direction",
  //run-time enumerated types
    "script",
    "music",
  //numeric types
    "number",
};
//Trailing comma there, and on most arrays, is intentional, so there's one less thing I have to think about
//  if I need to append things to them later on.

//Denotes first compile-time enumerated type... kinda pointless, but included for consistency
#define type_comp_enum type_fnc
//Denotes first run-time enumerated type
#define type_run_enum type_scr
//Denotes first numeric type
#define type_numeric type_num


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Compile-Time Enumerated Types
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Functions - elements of a script that have some number of parameters, themselves with their own types.
typedef enum{ fnc_null, fnc_quit, fnc_run, fnc_playBGM, fnc_count } FUNCTION;
//const omitted here so it can be stored with other non-const char* arrays later on in this code.
char* fnc_names[] = {
    "null",    //no-op
    "quit",    //exits script
    "run",     //runs the given script
    "play",    //plays the specified music, fading in for the given amount of time or instantly if zero
};

//Functions have additional data associated with them beyond the name
//Stores number of arguments for each function
const int fnc_arg_count[] = {
    0,0,1,2,
};
//Stores types of arguments for each function
//Technically defining it with int rather than VAR_TYPE here is arguably unsafe, but doing so makes a few
//  bookkeeping things simpler in parts of code not included here. And seriously, if you manage to make this
//  not work by including an int value here that isn't a VAR_TYPE, you deserve whatever you get.
const int* fnc_arg_types[] = {
    (int[]){},
    (int[]){},
    (int[]){type_scr},
    (int[]){type_mus, type_num},
};
//Contains the names of the arguments for each function, used solely in debugging.
//const again omitted for compatibility reasons, but this time for ones in other parts of the code.
char** fnc_arg_names[] = {
    (char*[]){},
    (char*[]){},
    (char*[]){"next"},
    (char*[]){"song", "fade"},
};


//Directions - relative direction
typedef enum{ dir_up, dir_down, dir_left, dir_right, dir_count } DIRECTION;
char* dir_names[] = {
    "up",
    "down",
    "left",
    "right",
};
//Directions, unlike functions, do not have any extra data associated with them.

//Here's where there's a little bit of weirdness, to minimize the potential mixing-up of memory, it 
//  makes sense to define the 'all_count' array here and the 'all_names' array later on, despite their clear
//  relationship to each other. This is something I'd like to have at the top of the file, after type_names,
//  but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it cleanly without either having to manually count
//  the various types or use a bunch of ugly bootstraps #define statements.
int all_count[type_count] = {
    fnc_count,
    dir_count,
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Run-Time Enumerated Types
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//This monster just exists to cut a bunch of boilerplate. Doesn't save much in this example with
//  two things to register, saves a ton in the real thing with nine.
//The important things to keep in mind here are that 'A' is the three-character code of the type being
//  registered to, 'name' is the string name of the thing being registered, and it makes local variable 'len'
//  which sometimes is used and sometimes is not later on.
#define REGISTER_THING(A) \
    if(A##_count == max_##A##_count){ ERROR(1, "Max number of %s registered!", type_names[type_##A]); }\
    for(int i=0; i<A##_count; i++){\
        if(str_compare(A##_names[i], name)){ ERROR(1, "Duplicate %s registered!", type_names[type_##A]); }\
    }\
    int len = strlen(name);\
    if(len >= max_##A##_name_len){ ERROR(1, "'%s' exceeds %s name length limits!", name, type_names[type_##A]); }\
    memcpy(A##_names[A##_count], name, len+1);\
    DEBUG("Registered %s '%s'", type_names[type_##A], name);\
    A##_count++;


//Script - a variable representing a script
//These numbers are arbitrary in this example, can be set to whatever makes sense for the implementation.
#define max_scr_count    256
#define max_scr_name_len 16
//I don't like this define, but don't see a way around it if I want to keep both a consistent '###_count'
//  syntax and a 'all_count[]' syntax.
#define scr_count all_count[type_scr]
char scr_names[max_scr_count][max_scr_name_len];
//This exists solely to build the 'all_names' array later on, to have consistency with other types.
char* scr_names_lnk[max_scr_count];

//There are some pre-defined scripts, determining what happens at startup or when opening a menu, for example.
//  They are overridden by loaded scripts that share a name with them, and exist as placeholders otherwise.
typedef enum{ scr_set_startup, scr_set_settings, scr_set_count } SCR_SET;
const char* scr_set_names[] = {
    "startup",
    "settings",
};
int scr_set[scr_set_count];
//Some more of these ugly defines... at least these aren't at risk of colliding with anything.
#define scr_startup scr_set[scr_set_startup]
#define scr_settings scr_set[scr_set_settings]

//Defined elsewhere, initializes memory for a newly loaded script.
int init_script(){return 0;}

int register_scr(const char* name){
    REGISTER_THING(scr);
    for( int i=0; i<scr_set_count; i++){
        if(str_compare(scr_set_names[i], name)){
            //The -1 here is because registerThing incremented scr_count.
            scr_set[i] = scr_count-1;
            DEBUG("Set script %s found!",name);
        }
    }
    return init_script();
}


//Music - names of pieces of music, also used as paths to the music files.
#define max_mus_count    64
#define max_mus_name_len 16
#define mus_count all_count[type_mus]
char mus_names[max_mus_count][max_mus_name_len];
char* mus_names_lnk[max_mus_count];

//Music, unlike scripts, has no additional initialization that needs doing here, at least in this example.
int register_mus(const char* name){
    REGISTER_THING(mus);
    return 0;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Numeric Types
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//These functions translate numbers from a string to whatever binary representation the implementation uses.
//  For the purposes of this example, we're assuming data is stored internally specifically as ints.
int num_parse(int* num, char* name){
    char* remainder;
    *num = strtol(name, &remainder, 10);
    if((*num==0 && name[0]!='0') || remainder[0]){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int (*numeric_parse[]) (int*, char*) = {
    num_parse,
};

//Finally the other half of all_count[]. Again, I'd love for this to be after type_names, but can't see how
//  to do it without a lot of messy referencing.
char** all_names[type_count] = {
    fnc_names,
    dir_names,
    scr_names_lnk,
    mus_names_lnk,
    NULL,          //Numbers do not have names.
};

//And the payoff
int searchNames(int type, int* value, char* name){
    if(type<0 || type>=type_count){ ERROR(1,"Unrecognized type.");}
    else if(type >= type_numeric){
        return (*numeric_parse[type-type_numeric])(value, name);
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<all_count[type]; i++){
            if(str_compare(all_names[type][i], name)){
                *value = i;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


//And now some tidying up...
//This is another boilerplate macro that saves a lot of space in the real version.
#define LINK_NAMES(A)\
    for(int i=0; i<max_##A##_count; i++){\
        A##_names_lnk[i] = &(A##_names[i][0]);\
    }

//This function sets up the arrays containing the names of run-time enumerated types, should be
//  run before any data is loaded.
//The trailing semicolons here aren't necessary, but are included for consistency in macro conventions.
int initTypes(){
    LINK_NAMES(scr);
    LINK_NAMES(mus);
    
    //You can also add default data here, for example if you want a 'silence' music without
    //actually having a 'silence.wav' file somewhere.
    register_mus("silence");
}

int main(){
    initTypes();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoops... should have known I'd miss something. my real code actually treats them as aliases in some context, which is why I didn't catch that, but it's actually a typo in this case. I rewrote this example code using more verbose variable names than in my real code, and that's a spot I missed. I'll do another look over now.

Comment: Fixed that and one other naming mistake (missed changing `compare` to `str_compare`) , tested this version on a compiler with default settings so should all be good now. Again, my apologies for the sloppiness.

Answer (score 4):

## General Observations

This is a personal preference, but I really don't like code that overuses macros: it is very hard to debug and maintain.

This question has horizontal scroll bars which is an indication that the lines are too long. Try to keep line lengths under 80 characters, and never go above 100 characters. This will make the code easier to read and maintain.

Generally all debug code should be contained within `#ifdef`s.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// Debug code
#endif
```

## Macro Names

Every one has macro names `DEBUG` and `ERROR`; in some cases compilers use `DEBUG` to indicate the mode they are in. It might be better to rename these 2 macros:

```
#define DEBUG(message,...) printf(message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERROR(code, message,...) printf(message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__); return code
```

to something line `DEBUG_PRINT` and `ERROR_PRINT`.

It is common practice to report errors to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(message,...) printf(message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
#define ERROR_PRINT(code, message,...) fprintf(stderr, message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__); return code
```

## Re-inventing the Wheel

It isn't clear why `int str_compare(const char* A, const char* B)` exists, since the C Standard Library provides [`strcmp()` and `strncmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). The C library functions are generally optimized so they will be faster. In any case `str_compare()` can be written using `strcmp()` or its relatives:

```
int str_compare(const char* A, const char* B) {
    if (!(B && A)) { return 0; }
    return (!strcmp(A, B)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice!
The preview of the question as I was editing it didn't have a horizontal scroll bar... I'll keep a closer eye on line lengths in the future, and be sure to check the final post as well.
I actually do have a much more robust definition for `DEBUG`/`ERROR` but left it out as irrelevant to the code at hand.
Regarding `str_compare`... I genuinely have no idea why I'm not using the library function. My best guess is that at one point I was trying to write this without using `string.h`, and I never bothered to update?

Comment: I would `strcmp(A, B) == 0` rather than negating and then using to switch a conditional.  (I would also rename the parameters to lower-case, so we can keep all-caps reserved for macros, too).

Answer (score 1):

### Debug code:

As already stated by @pacmaninbw in another answer:

*"All debug code should be contained within ifdef's."*

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// Debug code
#endif
```

But you might not want to pollute your code with hideous mazes of `#ifdef()s`. So here's an alternative:¹

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define D(x) do { x } while(0)
#else
#define D(x) do { } while(0)
#endif
```

Now the debug code can go inside `D(x);`.

---

### Numeric types:

Use `size_t` for sizes, cardinalities, or ordinal numbers.

From cpp.reference:

> size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).
>
> size_t is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting. Programs that use other types, such as unsigned int, for array
> indexing may fail on, e.g. 64-bit systems when the index exceeds
> UINT_MAX or if it relies on 32-bit modular arithmetic.

```
// for(int i=0; i<all_count[type]; i++)

for (size_t i = 0; i < all_count[type]; i++)
```

---

### Formatting:

Use one space around (on each side of) most binary and ternary operators (but not unary operators). It makes the code easier to read.

```
// for(int i=0; i<all_count[type]; i++)

for (size_t i = 0; i < all_count[type]; i++)
```

---

[1] — Credit: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE